# Trying to create a dial gauge in VB.net application

Tags: vb.net, gauge

I've been going in circles trying to figure out how to incorporate a dial control into a Windows form (without having to purchase a third party solution).  From the research I've done, it appears I need microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.  I attempted to install version 6.1.1 (from .nupkg) but receive the following installation error: "Could not install package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 6.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."  Any guidance/help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Arc graphic quality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54139910/7444103). Very *raw* design (*style* was not the point), but the base functionality is there. You're probably more interested in the notes.

Comment: I googles "dial gauge in .net" and got several hits for free ones.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Jimi/Mary.  I did Google search for the same thing.  The 'free' solutions are a bit misleading.  They end up be free trials.  I will try Jimi's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Jimi.  The link (Arc graphic quality) worked like a charm.  I needed to do a little tweaking to get this to work with VB, but it works.  I've attached the VB code.`

Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1

```
Dim GaugeValue As Single = 75 'move the needle with this value (0 - 100 percent)
Dim GaugeSweepAngle As Single = 270
Dim GaugeStartAngle As Single = 135

Private Sub Canvas_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Canvas.Paint
    Dim canvas As New Control
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    Dim outerRectangle = New Rectangle(10, 10, 180, 180)
    Dim innerRectangle = New Rectangle(30, 30, 140, 140)
    Dim blendRectangle = New Rectangle(10, 10, 180, 160)
    Dim innerCenter = New PointF(outerRectangle.Left + (outerRectangle.Width / 2), outerRectangle.Top + (outerRectangle.Height / 2))
    Dim gaugeLength = (outerRectangle.Width / 2) - 2

    Using Path = New GraphicsPath
        Path.AddPie(outerRectangle, GaugeStartAngle, GaugeSweepAngle)
        Path.AddPie(innerRectangle, GaugeStartAngle, GaugeSweepAngle)
        innerRectangle.Inflate(-1, -1)

        Using pen = New Pen(Color.Black, 3.0F)
            Using backgroundbrush = New SolidBrush(canvas.BackColor)
                Using gradientBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(blendRectangle, Color.Green, Color.Red, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal)
                    Dim blend = New Blend
                    Dim factors(0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0)
                    Dim positions(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)

                    gradientBrush.Blend = blend
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(gradientBrush, Path)
                    e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, Path)
                    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(backgroundbrush, innerRectangle)

                    Using format = New StringFormat
                        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                        innerRectangle.Location = New Point(innerRectangle.X, innerRectangle.Y + canvas.Font.Height)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(GaugeValue.ToString() + "%", canvas.Font, Brushes.Black, innerRectangle, format)

                        Using mx = New Matrix
                            mx.RotateAt(GaugeStartAngle + 90 + (GaugeValue * (GaugeSweepAngle / 100)), innerCenter)
                            e.Graphics.Transform = mx
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, innerCenter, New PointF(innerCenter.X, innerCenter.Y - gaugeLength))
                            e.Graphics.ResetTransform()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

End Class`.